# remove page titles from naviation menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We have a website www.bosworthsgc.co.uk  built using wordpress

we have had some custom jpegs made which I have added to the menu

However the original wording of the page also shows up

For expample on the Plants tab - as well as our jpeg with the logo and word plants there is the word Plants which I need to remove

Is there a plugin available that would do this or some other way to do this

Thanks

Comment: In your wordpress backend go to where the images are stored and edit the image taking out its name e.g. Plants  wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Plants5-140x140.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Look in style.css and find the selector that reads;

```
.tiled-menu > li > .menu-item-wrap > a{
}
```

And add text-indent: -9000em; so it reads something like this;

```
.tiled-menu > li > .menu-item-wrap > a{    
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 8px 13px;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -9000em;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Simply removing the name from the li item will stop people with CSS disabled from viewing the menu items and will not be cool for users with screen readers.

Comment: Thanks - being a newbie to this I am not sure where to go to find this. Can you advise please?  Thanks

Comment: The core stylesheet in Wordpress is style.css in the root folder of your installation. :)
You should be able to find the style you're after in there.